# finding students with highest and lowest credits in array in python

Tags: python, arrays, csv

firstly, i apologize for my bad english as it is not my native language but i will try my best to explain everything as best as i can. i am trying to find students with highest and lowest credits from a .csv file
[here is my csv looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPl32.png)

and here is my code so far:
i appended the first names into first_names array(same thing with the last name and credits)

```
def arrays(i):
    import csv
    with open('FCredits.csv','r+') as f_data:  
            csv_reader = csv.reader(f_data, delimiter=',')
            first_names = []
            last_names = []
            f_credits = []
            for row in csv_reader:
                    csv_reader = csv.reader(f_data, delimiter=',')
                    first_name = row[0]
                    last_name = row[1]
                    f_credit = row[2]
                    first_names.append(first_name)
                    last_names.append(last_name)
                    f_credits.append(f_credit)  
            find_min_max(first_names,last_names,f_credits)
```

but then stuck on the next part

```
def find_min_max(first_names,last_names,f_credits):
    minVal, maxVal = [],[]
    for i in f_credits:
            minVal.append(f_credits)
            maxVal.append(f_credits)
    print(min(minVal))
    print(max(minVal))
```

basically, what i wanted to do on the second part is to print out the student with lowest and highest amount of credits and write them in a new csv file but gave up halfway.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that I have noted in your question:

- The highest or lowest mark can be scored by multiple people.
- That means the output may or may not be single and so a list is required.

Please see my code below:

```
def get_min_max(first_names,last_names,f_credits):
    max_value = max(f_credits)
    min_value = min(f_credits)
    minVal = []
    maxVal = []
    for element in zip(first_names, last_names, f_credits):
        if element[-1] == max_value:
            maxVal.append(element)
        elif element[-1] == min_value:
            minVal.append(element)
    print(len(maxVal), maxVal)
    print(len(minVal), minVal)
    return maxVal, minVal
```

For the If .. Elif part i suggest that you use a list comprehension to make the code concise and faster. I have written it this way so that you understand it better.

You may also want to read about min, max and zip functions of python from the official python documentation.